# Why does the preprocessor replace comments by single space instead of removing them in C language

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I've read that comments in C language are replaced by single spaces while pre-processing. In the specification

> The program is split into tokens separated by white-space characters; *comments are
> replaced by a single space*[emphasis added]. Then preprocessing directives are obeyed, and macros
> (Pars.A.12.3-A.12.10) are expanded.

Is there a specific reason behind this choice?

I've seen this example

```
#include <stdio.h>
int/*This is a comment*/main(){
    return 0;
}
```

If we don't replace the comment with a single space the above would raise errors. However, it appears a bad practice to write comments in this manner. Is there any other reason why replacing a comment with a single space instead of just striping it is helpful?

Comment: I assume you want another answer than *the specification says so*? Unless you're lucky that someone who was there when this decision was made happens upon your question, I think all we can do is speculate.

Comment: If a comment was replaced by nothing `int/*This is a comment*/main()` would be seen as `intmain()` and it would not compile. That's probably one of the main reasons. But as you already noticed such comments are poor practice. Just don't bother and put your energy into something else.

Comment: hehe `int long/* gotcha */john = 42;`

Comment: the standard is the law, and laws must be clear regardless of whether that's good or not

Comment: One of the earlier stages in a typical compiler's pipeline is converting text into tokens. All whitespace and comments are likely converted to the same token (and it's very unlikely that comments are converted to a space).

Answer (score 4):

```
int a/* comment */b;
```

If it weren't replaced by a space the above would compile as `int ab;`. I would argue this would be worse than the current specs.